# why isnt my whale object inheriting properies from the mammals object?

Tags: javascript

I'm experimenting with prototype inheritance, when I typed this into the console I didn't get an error but its doesn't seem to be inheriting properly.

```
var organism = {
    hasCellDivision: true
};

var animals = Object.create(organism);
animals.hasNervousSystem = true;

var mammals = Object.create(animals);
mammals.legs = 4, hasBrain = true, hasBlood = true, heads = 1;

var plants = Object.create(organism);
plants.hasNervousSystem = false;

var whale = Object.create(mammals);
whale.leg = 0;

var insects = Object.create(mammals);
insects.legs = 6, hasBrain = false, hasGanglia = true;
```

Comment: What is expected result ? You have few variables which are not keys of the object..

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is here

```
var mammals = Object.create(animals);
mammals.legs = 4, hasBrain = true, hasBlood = true, heads = 1;
```

should be

```
var mammals = Object.create(animals);
mammals.legs = 4, mammals.hasBrain = true, mammals.hasBlood = true, mammals.heads = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're typing this literally into console, it's because you're doing things like

```
mammals.legs=4, hasBrain=true, ...
```

instead of

```
mammals.legs=4; mammals.hasBrain=true; ...
```

You aren't getting errors because you're just setting global variables called `hasBrain` and the others.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood the usages of the `,` operator. Also, minor type at `mammals.leg`.

The following works:

```js
var organism = {
    hasCellDivision: true
};

var animals = Object.create(organism);
animals.hasNervousSystem = true;

var mammals = Object.create(animals);
mammals.legs = 4;
mammals.hasBrain = true;
mammals.hasBlood = true;
mammals.heads = 1;

var plants = Object.create(organism);
plants.hasNervousSystem = false;

var whale = Object.create(mammals);
whale.legs = 0;

var insects = Object.create(mammals);
insects.legs = 6;
insects.hasBrain = false;
insects.hasGanglia = true;

console.log(whale);
```

Answer (score -2):

It is inheriting! It might be the typo:

```
whale.leg=0;
```

should be:

```
whale.legs = 0;
```

Either way, if I paste your code into the console and type `whale.legs` it outputs `4`.